# SSL certificate for www sub-domain not valid on DigitalOcean WikiJS installation

Tags: https, security-certificate

I have set up WikiJS using a DigitalOcean droplet. If I access my site via `https://example.com` everything is fine. If I access it via `https://www.example.com` I get a certificate warning due a domain name mismatch.

I generated a new certificate via Let's Encrypt using a wildcard which can be found on my server:

```
Certificate Name: example.com
    Serial Number: 37c9c76cd62e06a55c92bf74354a68e2c8a
    Key Type: ECDSA
    Domains: example.com *.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2023-07-22 19:04:51+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

If I go to the `www` sub-domain and view the certificate which has the warning, it has a Serial Number of `04:32:F5:44:8F:6C:EA:3D:0E:82:A1:06:CD:01:8B:A8:3F:A1`, which is different to the one I created.

Reading the documentation (https://docs.requarks.io/install/config), can specify a path to the certificate, however if I navigate to `etc/wiki/` on my server I'd expect a config.yml file to exist, but the directory is empty. So I have no idea where that config files exists so I can edit it to point my WikiJS installation to use the certificate with the wildcard domain.

Additionally, there's no way to provide a wildcard to the `docker create` command as noted in that same documentation.

I have tried restarting the docker container after creating the new certificate.

If I go to the WikiJS SSL configuration page, the expiration is different, to confirm it's using a different certificate:
[image]

Side note: If I click "Renew Certificate" I get a Network Access error which I haven't had before and the expiration date doesn't advance, so it isn't actually renewing.

I want to have an SSL certification which covers my domain example.com and any sub-domains... What am I doing wrong?